# tlv320aicx(audio codec) device tree

Tags: audio, kernel-modules, device-tree

I'm trying to get solve a kernel message that I'm getting from the [`tlv320aicx` driver. (linux-5.4)](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/sound/soc/codecs/tlv320aic3x.c)

The original error was

```
Invalid supply voltage(s) AVDD: -22, DVDD: -22
```

I was able to locate to the function `int regulator_get_voltage_rdev(struct regulator_dev rdev)` in `core.c` (`kernel/linux-5.4/drivers/regulator/core.c`) which returns `-EINVAL` (this is `22`).

It seemed that I needed to add some additional supply information in the device tree. The device tree binding for the `tlv320aicx` showed that I should [add the supplies](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/sound/tlv320aic3x.txt#L11).

And this is the [regulator binding](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/regulator/regulator.yaml) explaining what I can add in the regulator node.

See my device tree entry below. The `IOVDD` and `DVDD` supplies it still takes a dummy regulator. However, I'm getting a different error for the `AVDD`

```
Failed to request supplies: -517
```

which is originated form the `tlv320aic` driver. I can't seem to figure out what I need to add in the device tree for it to take that value as the input voltage.

```
/*audio codec*/
tlv320aic3106: tlv320aic3106@18 {
    #sound-dai-cells = <0>;
    compatible = "ti,tlv320aic3106";
    reg = <0x18>;

    ai3x-micbias-vg = <2>;
    /*ai3x-ocmv = <2>;*/
    AVDD-supply = <&regulator_analog>;
    //IOVDD-supply = <&regulator_digital>;
    // DRVDD-supply = <&regulator>;
    // DVDD-supply = <&regulator>;
};
    
regulator_analog: tlv320aic3106@18 {
   //AVDD-supply = <3300000>;
   //AVDD = <3300000>;
   regulator-min-microvolt = <3200000>;
   regulator-max-microvolt = <3600000>;
   regulator-always-on;
   vin-supply = <33000000>;
};
```